# Delete rows based on the quantity of the last row in the same group

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table like this

```
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Name    | Task             | Team | Date | Month   |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Market study     | C    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Customer service | C    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 2 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
```

I have a table like the above. First I want to identify the rows and categorized the by 'Month'. Then I want to find the Month in which there was less than 2 days in it and delete them (in this case Month 2 only has 'Date' 1 so it should be deleted). I would like my final table to be:

```
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Name    | Task             | Team | Date | Month   |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Market study     | C    | 2    | Month 1 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| John    | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| Michael | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 3 |
+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
```

What should I do? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using **groupby** and **filter** method in pandas:

```
df.groupby('Month').filter(lambda g:(g['Date']>1).any())
```

Answer (score 1):

First group by month, then use the `nunique` method to get the months with a specific number of dates:

```
table = { "Name": ["John", "Michael", "Joanna", "John", "Michael", "Joanna", "John", "Michael", 
"Joanna", "John", "Michael", "Joanna", "John", "Michael"],
"Task": ["Market study", "Customer service", "Accounting", "Accounting", "Customer service", "Market study", "Customer service", "Market study", "Customer service", "Market study", "Customer service", "Accounting", "Customer service", "Accounting"],
"Team":["A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B"],
"Date": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
"Month": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
}

grp = pd.DataFrame(table).groupby("Month")
unique = grp["Date"].nunique()
to_remove = unique[unique == 1].index.values
# to_remove = array([2], dtype=int64)
```

Then, in `df` you can remove rows where month is in `to_remove`.